# Circuit with capactor in parallel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits

I have a problem with this circuit.
[image]

The switch T was left open for a long time and the capacitator C "charged" up to V0. Then the switch is closed and I need to calculate the current that flows through 2R. If I'm not mistaken, C should start working as a battery that goes "against" the original battery, but I can't figure out how I should approach this (I tried to calculate the parallel between 2R and 4R then use kirchhoff laws but with no result).

I could ignore C if I was asked the current after "infinite" time, but I'm asked the instant T closes.

The correct answer should be $\frac{V_0}{3R}$.

Comment: "The switch T was left open for a long time and the capacitor C "charged" up to V0.". Explain why you think the voltage across C will be V0 after along time with the switch open?

Comment: I'm honestly not sure about that myself. I was originally asked to calculate the current in the circuit when T was left open for a long time. That's why I obviously ignored 4R and then expected the voltage across C to be equal to Vo, because it had "infinite" time to charge and stabilize, so I considered C to be a cut. I was left with R and 2R.
I used this same thought to analyze the situation when T closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, when the switch is open a long time the voltage across the capacitor is not $V_0$. It is

$$V_{C}=V_{0}\frac{2R}{2R+R}=\frac{2}{3}V_{0}$$

That's because after a long time an ideal capacitor in a dc circuit looks like an open circuit.

Secondly, you can't change the voltage across an ideal capacitor instantaneously, i.e., in zero time. Therefore the voltage across the capacitor the instant the switch closes is the same as the instant before it closes, in this case $\frac{2}{3}V_o$. So now you can treat the capacitor as a $\frac{2}{3}V_o$ battery, but only to calculate the current in the circuit the instant after closing the switch since the battery will discharge in time.

From here you should be able to confirm that the current in the 2R resistor is $\frac{V_o}{3R}$.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could you explain how you obtained Vc? I tried obtaining it by calculating the Req (ignoring the capacitor), then the total current, then decomposing and supposing Vc is equal to the voltage across all the parallel branches; obtained 4/7 * Vo so turned out to be the wrong approach. When you say that I can now treat C as a battery, can I use kirchhoff with 2 loops and "fusing" r4 and r2 like this? https://i.imgur.com/9CO6vBr.png Or are there actually more loops? Or is even kirchhoff not needed.

Comment: You are way overcomplicating this problem. It's a simple voltage divider. The current through the capacitor is zero and the voltage across it is the voltage across  2R. The voltage across 2R is the current through 2R times its resistance. From Ohms law for the series combination of R and 2R, the current in 2R is $$I=\frac{V_{o}}{(R+2R)}=\frac{V_{o}}{3R}$$ The voltage across 2R is then $$(I)(2R)=\frac {V_{o}}{3R}2R=\frac{2}{3}V_{o}$$